# Why does mconcat require a list rather than a Foldable?

Tags: haskell, monoids, foldable

While looking at the definition of [`Monoid`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Prelude.html#t:Monoid) I noticed that [`mconcat`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Prelude.html#v:mconcat) has the following definition ([source](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#mconcat)):

```hs
mconcat :: Monoid a => [a] -> a
mconcat = foldr mappend mempty
```

Why would the signature limit this to `[a]` rather than the more generic `Foldable` like this?

```hs
mconcat' :: (Foldable t, Monoid a) => t a -> a
mconcat' = foldr mappend mempty
```

Is this for historical reasons? Or would this more generic implementation make it harder for specific types to provide an optimized version of it, as is the case e.g. for `[]` which uses list comprehension ([source](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#line-301))?

Comment: The old version of `foldr` only worked on lists iirc.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Though I don't know of an actual discussion about such a proposal, here are some conceivable reasons:

- The generalised function already exists as [`fold` from `Foldable`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Foldable.html#v:fold).
- In fact, `mconcat` might be of some use as an implementation of `fold @[_]`, which might be more efficient than the usual default for some monoids. (I took this idea from [GHC issue #17123](https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/issues/17123).)
- Changing class method signatures leads to churn, as instances everywhere must be adjusted accordingly, and so it tends to be done only when there is a pressing need. (By the way, `Monoid` itself was, [though a carefully planned process](https://prime.haskell.org/wiki/Libraries/Proposals/SemigroupMonoid), reworked in order to add `Semigroup` as a superclass, which may or may not support my point.)
- The specialised type of `mconcat` is meaningful, reflecting how [the list type is an encoding of the free monoid in Haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54168130/2751851). (Another interesting factoid is that it is possible to implement both `mempty` and `mappend` in terms of `mconcat`.)

Comment: Thanks for this list, really helpful! Just realized that I could have found `fold` myself by simply [hoogling `(Foldable t, Monoid m) => t m -> m`](https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=(Foldable%20t%2C%20Monoid%20m)%20%3D%3E%20t%20m%20-%3E%20m). I also came across an interesting article titled [Synonyms in base](https://tech.fpcomplete.com/haskell/tutorial/synonyms), which lists this and other examples of similar functions.